# Update field in db avg value from other table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
UPDATE `users` u  
   SET u.`user_rating`= (SELECT avg(rating) 
                           FROM `rating` r 
                          WHERE (r.prof_id=u.id AND r.is_prof_send=0) 
                             OR (r.user_id=u.id AND r.is_prof_send=1))
                            AND u.id in(3)
```

Hello, I need to update rating in first table using avg value from second. I've added example, which return 1 as avg every time, but inner select returns correct value. What's wrong with it?

Comment: The published query is not syntactically correct - did you transcribe it accurately? Where for example is the table that is being aliased as e (as in e.condition1)? You can improve this question by publishing sample data an expected output.

Comment: I've replaced some conditions with condition+number, but it's good, and user ids - string like (1,2,3,4,5)

Comment: Please publish your actual non working query.

Comment: Added my actual query

Comment: at first glance, stating `AND u.id in(3)` after the second parentheses following `r.is_prof_send=1` is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statements MySql does not allow references of the target table in subqueries like your code.
What you can use is joins.
Try this way (if this is the logic that you want to apply):

```
UPDATE `users` u  
 INNER JOIN (
             SELECT u.id, avg(r.rating) avgrating
               FROM `users` u INNER JOIN `rating` r 
                 ON (r.prof_id=u.id AND r.is_prof_send=0) 
                 OR (r.user_id=u.id AND r.is_prof_send=1)
              WHERE u.id IN (3)
              GROUP BY u.id
             ) t ON t.id = u.id
   SET u.`user_rating`= t.avgrating
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT returns a table, not a value.

Your query looks like ANSI SQL syntax.

1. Try adding the same name for `avg(rating)` as the field you want to update `avg(rating) as rating`
2. Pay attention that you placed `and u.id in(user ids)` after the SELECT, so you have `(SELECT...) and u.id in(user ids)` - It is boolean

```
UPDATE `users` u SET u.`rating`= 
    (
    SELECT avg(rating) as rating
    FROM `ratings` r 
    WHERE
        (r.prof_id=u.id and r.condition1)
        or (r.user_id=u.id and r.condition2)
        and u.id in(user ids)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `u.id in (3)` is misplaced.  Does this do what you want?

```
UPDATE users u  
   SET u.user_rating = (SELECT AVG(rating) 
                        FROM rating r 
                        WHERE (r.prof_id = u.id AND r.is_prof_send = 0) OR
                              (r.user_id = u.id AND r.is_prof_send = 1)
                       )
   WHERE u.id IN (3);
```